# как удалить мелкие(и не совсем) шумы с бинарного изображения не зависимо от освещения?

Tags: python, opencv

Есть изображение дороги в бинарном виде, с помощью threshold  пытаюсь выделить только дефекты на дороге(трещины, ямы),вопрос такой как удалить этот шум, что бы при изменении освещения он снова не появился? Ниже код который я пробовал.

```
rgb_image = cv2.cvtColor(masked, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
birdEye = np.minimum(masked, birdEye_value)
#cv2.imshow("birdEye_img", birdEye)
gray1 = cv2.cvtColor(birdEye, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

gray1 = cv2.medianBlur(gray1,5)
#blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray1, (3, 3), 0)

cv2.imshow('HSV_im', HSV_im)
ret, threshold = cv2.threshold(gray1, min_tresh, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
adthreshold = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray1, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 91,5)
cv2.imshow('adthreshold ', adthreshold )

cv2.imshow('treshold', threshold)
#canny = cv2.Canny(gray1,canny_val,250)
#cv2.imshow("canny", canny)

kernel_o = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (4, 4))
kernel_cl = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (10, 10))
open = cv2.morphologyEx(HSV_im, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel_o)
close = cv2.morphologyEx(open, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel_cl)
close = cv2.morphologyEx(close, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel_cl)
#k = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ERODE, (15, 20))#erode
#closing = cv2.morphologyEx(threshold, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, k)

#closed = cv2.erode(closing, None, iterations=3)
#cv2.imshow("erode", closed)
#closed = cv2.dilate(closed, None, iterations=3)
#num_labels, labels, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(canny, 8, cv2.CV_32S)
#birdEye = np.minimum(masked, birdEye_value)
#cv2.imshow("birdEye_img", birdEye)
gray1 = cv2.cvtColor(birdEye, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

gray1 = cv2.medianBlur(gray1,5)
#blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray1, (3, 3), 0)

cv2.imshow('HSV_im', HSV_im)
ret, threshold = cv2.threshold(gray1, min_tresh, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)


cv2.imshow('treshold', threshold)
#canny = cv2.Canny(gray1,canny_val,250)
#cv2.imshow("canny", canny)

kernel_o = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (4, 4))
kernel_cl = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (10, 10))
open = cv2.morphologyEx(HSV_im, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel_o)
close = cv2.morphologyEx(open, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel_cl)
close = cv2.morphologyEx(close, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel_cl)
#k = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ERODE, (15, 20))#erode
#closing = cv2.morphologyEx(threshold, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, k)

#closed = cv2.erode(closing, None, iterations=3)
#cv2.imshow("erode", closed)
#closed = cv2.dilate(closed, None, iterations=3)
#num_labels, labels, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(canny, 8, cv2.CV_32S)
#birdEye = np.minimum(masked, birdEye_value)
#cv2.imshow("birdEye_img", birdEye)
gray1 = cv2.cvtColor(birdEye, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

gray1 = cv2.medianBlur(gray1,5)
#blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray1, (3, 3), 0)

cv2.imshow('HSV_im', HSV_im)
ret, threshold = cv2.threshold(gray1, min_tresh, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)


cv2.imshow('treshold', threshold)
#canny = cv2.Canny(gray1,canny_val,250)
#cv2.imshow("canny", canny)

kernel_o = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (4, 4))
kernel_cl = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (10, 10))
open = cv2.morphologyEx(HSV_im, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel_o)
close = cv2.morphologyEx(open, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel_cl)
close = cv2.morphologyEx(close, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel_cl)
#k = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ERODE, (15, 20))#erode
#closing = cv2.morphologyEx(threshold, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, k)

#closed = cv2.erode(closing, None, iterations=3)
#cv2.imshow("erode", closed)
#closed = cv2.dilate(closed, None, iterations=3)
#num_labels, labels, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(canny, 8, cv2.CV_32S)
#kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3, 3))
#closed = cv2.morphologyEx(canny, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
#cv2.line(gray1, 100,300, (0, 255, 0), thickness=2)
```

изображение в бинарном виде с наложенной маской
[image: изображение в бинарном виде с наложенной маской]
исходное изображение
[image: исходное изображение]
просто для примера
[image: просто для примера]

Answer (score 0):

Самый тупой вариант, это сформировать "трещину" в массив нумпай, затем проходя по каждому элементу вычислить который цвет она бы имела не будь трещины (взять верхнюю координату пикселя, нижнюю, правую, левую координаты за трещиной сумировать и разделить на 4) затем перезаписать данный пиксель (элемент нумпай).
Встроеных функций в cv2, skimage я не помню.

Comment: спасибо что отозвались, но я не могу понять ход ваших мыслей и как это могло бы выглядеть. Пока я остановился на этом :
    adthreshold=cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray1,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, threshold_value1 ,threshold_value2)
    kernel_o = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3, 3))
    kernel_cl = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (10, 10))
    close = cv2.morphologyEx(adthreshold, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel_cl)
    open = cv2.morphologyEx(close, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel_o)
Но это не оптимальное решение для меня

Comment: Имеется ввиду обработка массива нумпай напрямую (без библиотеки cv2): для начала получаем массив нумпай с областью корректировки, затем проходим по каждому элементу массива (который здесь будет равен пикселю) вычисляя его цвет. После заменяем элементы в массиве исходно изображения. Данный метод подойдёт, только если область шума одноцветная, то есть шум на шахматном фоне будет превращён в серый но с переходом.